# TextBox value used in url parameter

Tags: asp.net, html, postbackurl

I have an ASP.NET site and I have a page which uses a url query string:

> routeToScene.aspx?RunNumber=3253665

This loads fine when I pass the parameter `RunNumber=XXXXXXX` in the URL.

What I want to do is load this page by passing the `RunNumber=XXXXXXX` via a text box on another page called: `routToHospitalParam.aspx` with a simple submit button that takes the value in the textbox and passes it to the URL of the second page. This should be simple and I feel foolish for not finding an answer.

This is the code in the `routeToHospitalParam.aspx` page...

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Width="80px" MaxLength="7" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" PostBackUrl="~/MAP/routeToHospital.aspx" + TextBox1.text />
```

The issue is when I try use the `TextBox1.value` (assuming that is correct) in the `PostBackUrl` which loads the other page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

In aspx change code to handle onclick event:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
OnClick="Button1_OnClick" />
```

In codebehind button click event redirect user with queryprameter:

```
protected void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EvenArgs e)
{
  Response.redirect("~/MAP/routeToHospital.aspx?RunNumber=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(TextBox1.text));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the best method and I only had to remove the ';' to make it work in my VB code.

Answer (score 1):

You really want to take a look at [Cross-Page Posting in ASP.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178139%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

It uses the `PreviousPage` property of the `Page` object. That was you can do away with trying to pass the value via the querystring.

e.g.

**C#**

```
TextBox textBox = (TextBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("TextBox1");
```

**VB**

```
Dim textBox as TextBox = CType(Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("TextBox1"), TextBox)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try some jQuery function like below to set postback url:

```
$(function(){
$('#Button1').click(function(){
    $('#Button1').attr("action", "/MAP/routeToHospital.aspx?RunNumber=" + $('#TextBox1').val());
   });
});
```

or add this on blur event of textbox:

```
$(function(){
$('#TextBox1').blur(function(){
    $('#Button1').attr("action", "/MAP/routeToHospital.aspx?RunNumber=" + $('#TextBox1').val());
   });
});
```